# Xamarin.Forms - Certificate Pinning using custom HttpMessageHandlers

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm working on a multi-platform app using Xamarin.Forms that supports Android, iOS, & UWP. I'm looking at implementing Certificate Pinning with an internal API that this application uses. I'm not really an expert when it comes to SSL Certificates & I am new to the general concept of certificate/public key pinning, though I'm coming to an understanding of what needs to be done to implement this. One thing that I am struggling with though is how I can verify that I have the right public key to compare with when I'm debugging the app.

Our app makes API calls using a basic System.Net.Http.HttpClient, and we use a DependencyService to pass a platform specific HttpMessageHandler to the client to use. Because we're using NSUrlSessionHandler for iOS & AndroidClientHandler for Android (UWP uses a HttpClientHandler), we unfortunately can't utilize the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback property to handle this, as the native handlers don't support it. Luckily, I've been able to find some sample code that shows how this can be done for the Android & iOS platforms that I'm looking at now, and I've been able to figure out something that seems to work nicely for UWP. The iOS/Android sample that I've been looking at is this GitHub project: https://github.com/basdecort/Xamarin/tree/master/CertificatePinning

Here's the code that I have worked out for UWP's HttpMessageHandler that seems to do the trick

```
    private static readonly string[] PublicKeys =
    {
        "3082010A0282010100<PublicKey1>0203010001" // multiple keys will be pinned, hence the array
    };

    public HttpMessageHandler GetHandler(bool shouldAutoRedirect)
    {
        var retval = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip,
            AllowAutoRedirect = shouldAutoRedirect,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = PinPublicKey,
        };

        return retval;
    }

    private static bool PinPublicKey(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, X509Certificate2 certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (certificate == null || chain == null)
            return false;

        if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return false;

        // Verify against the known public key within the certificate
        var pk = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();

        return PublicKeys.Contains(pk.ToUpperInvariant());
    }
```

Working with this code, its very clear to verify that the public key that I'm expecting is correct. The pk variable value includes the public key modulus that I can see when I look at the certificate through Google Chrome, in between the prefix & exponent characters.

With the sample implementations on Android & iOS though, the string I have to review when debugging isn't as nice, and I've so far struggled with decoding the public key into a more readable string like I can see when I'm debugging UWP.

Android (I've just included the relevant methods in this sample):

```
public class CustomPublicKeyManager : Java.Lang.Object, IX509TrustManager
{
    private static readonly string[] PublicKeys; // Same as UWP sample code
    public void CheckServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, string authType)
    {
        if (!ValidateIntermediate(chain))
        {
        //code to handle failed check
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateCert(X509Certificate certificate)
    {
        var pubKeyString = Android.Util.Base64.EncodeToString(certificate.PublicKey.GetEncoded(), Android.Util.Base64Flags.Default).Replace("\n", "");
        return PublicKeys.Contains(pubKeyString.ToUpperInvariant());
    }

    private bool ValidateIntermediate(X509Certificate[] chain)
    {
        if (chain.Length <= 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return ValidateCert(chain[1]);
    }
}
```

In this case, pubKeyString stores a string with a prefix of "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA" and an exponent of "QIDAQAB" (with the encoded public key in between). I've tried searching for ways to convert this string to something more readable and easier to verify (and I've also played around with the different methods I've seen available to me on the Android objects), but I've had no such luck. Is it possible to convert this encoded string to the value that I see in UWP, and if so, is there a good example of how that can be done?

I'm facing a similar issue of encountering an encoded string in my attempt to make a custom implementation of NSUrlSessionHandlerDelegate.DidReceiveChallenge that includes pinning on iOS, so I have the same question for this platform as I do for Android.

```
        public override void DidReceiveChallenge(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionTask task, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
        {
            // other code above. This is the pinning code
            var serverCertChain = challenge.ProtectionSpace.ServerSecTrust;
            if (ValidateIntermediatePublicKey(serverCertChain))
            {
                completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.PerformDefaultHandling, challenge.ProposedCredential);
            }
            else
            {
                completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, null);
            }
        }

        private static bool ValidateIntermediatePublicKey(SecTrust securitySecTrust)
        {
            var first = securitySecTrust[1].DerData;
            var firstString = first.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);

            // How to convert firstString into a more readable format?

            return PublicKeys.Contains(firstString.ToUpperInvariant());
        }
```

Comment: [For android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.android.net.androidmessagehandler.trustedcerts?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12#xamarin-android-net-androidmessagehandler-trustedcerts), you can try using 'AndroidMessageHandler.TrustedCerts' to verify certificates. Whichever the case, the certificate(s) must be stored in this property in order for AndroidMessageHandler to configure the request to accept the server certificate.

Comment: For iOS, you can try using [HttpClientHandler .ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-httpclienthandler-servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback) for validation.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Thank you for your replies. I will look into the Android suggestion in more detail shortly. Regarding the suggestion on iOS, I am using NSUrlSessionHandler (and not HttpClientHandler), which doesn't have the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback property available to me. I found this post on Xamarin's GitHub page that seems to suggest that this is isn't supported, which is why I'm attempting a workaround to the issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4170

Comment: Pin multiple public keys for server certificate, you would add individual entries as items in an array to the Info.plist file of your app. You can refer to this apple documentation:https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=g9ejcf8y

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Thank you so much for the additional information. The Android & iOS solutions both offered a new way of certificate pinning that I hadn't seen before, and I think they will help a lot.

I just have one last question/confirmation. The iOS method you sent of adding to the plist is pinning against the public keys, like how my UWP code is handling pinning, correct? Whereas the Android solution of using the TrustedCerts property is pinning against the certificates themselves (and not the public keys). Is there a way on Android to pin against the public key rather than the cert?

Comment: Pinning against the public key is more ideal, as then we wouldn't need to rebuild the application whenever the certificate is set to expire with a new certificate. But if pinning against the certificate is the only way, then it is at least better than nothing.

Comment: For Android, please note that certificate pinning, you should always include a backup key so that if you are forced to switch to new keys or change CAs (when pinning to a CA certificate or an intermediate of that CA), your app's connectivity is unaffected. For pinning public keys, you can refer to this Android developer documentation:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet/reference/org/chromium/net/CronetEngine.Builder#public-cronetengine.builder-addpublickeypins-string-hostname,-setbyte[]-pinssha256,-boolean-includesubdomains,-date-expirationdate

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Thank you very much for the link on public key pinning with Android. That looks pretty similar to the iOS solution of using the plist definitions, which is great. The only downside with it that I see is that I wasn't able to find any indication that the addPublicKeyPins method is usable & available within Xamarin.Android. However, I did find that if I switch from using AndroidClientHandler to using AndroidMessageHandler instead, the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback becomes available to me, and I can make Android work just like UWP